# Why, and how, does an answer become a 'community wiki' answer?

Tags: support

This [answer](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/48516) is no longer from @Lucian but has become 'community wiki Lucian'.

How and why does this occur ?

---

Edit : I tried to point to the answer in my link above. But the link points to the question not the answer. How can I link directly to the answer?

Comment: I edited to include the direct link to answer. You can get this link from the share link on an answer. Note that when you copy the link it will include two numbers at the end, the first is the answer id, the second is your user id which you can chop off if you like.

Comment: @Soldarnal Thank you. Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the user ticking the box labelled "Community wiki" at the bottom of the answer form.

Several years ago it also used to be the case that a large number of edits (I'm not sure of exactly how many, maybe a couple dozen) would forcibly convert your answer to a wiki answer. This no longer happens, but old posts aren't switched back automatically (though they could be by a mod.)

Every post, both questions and answers, has a "share" link beneath it. Copy what it gives you to have a direct link to the individual post.

Comment: Many thanks. Appreciated.